# Reactive Template with compex object

Tags: meteor

I want to render a reactive template based on this document:

```
Sprint: 
    WorkStories:
        Tasks
```

I know this can be done by making a Meteor collection for each "level," but that means the result  is actually being stored as a seperate document in the database. I want to know if its possible to have one collection/document for `Sprint`, that has standard collection of `WorkStories` with a standard collection of `Tasks` each, rendered to a reactive template.

I've seen [Meteor.deps.Context][1], but I can't figure out how to wire it up (or even if it's the right tool), and none of the examples do anything like this.

I've also seen [this question][2], but he seems to be asking about connecting related-but-separate documents, not rendering a single document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because [database queries on collections are already reactive variables](http://docs.meteor.com/#reactivity) on the client, the below will render **one** `Sprint` document with **nested** `WorkStories` that has **nested** `Tasks` in a template:

HTML:

```
<head>
    <title>Sprints Example</title>
</head>

<body>
    {{> sprints }}
</body>

<template name="sprints">
  {{#each items}}
    <div>Name: {{name}}</div>
        {{#each this.WorkStories}}
            <div>{{name}}</div>
            {{#each this.Tasks}}
                <div>{{name}}</div>
            {{/each}}
        {{/each}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Javascript:

```
Sprints = new Meteor.Collection("sprints");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.sprints.items = function () {
      return Sprints.find({});
  };
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.startup(function () {
        if (Sprints.find().count() === 0) {
            Sprints.insert({ name: 'sprint1', WorkStories: [{ name: 'workStory1', Tasks: [{ name: 'task1' }, { name: 'task2' }, { name: 'task3' }] }, { name: 'workStory2', Tasks: [{ name: 'task1' }, { name: 'task2' }, { name: 'task3' }] }] });
        }
  });
}
```

**UPDATE WITH ANSWER**

Per @Paul-Young's comment below, the problem with my usage of `$set` was the lack of quotes in the update. Once the nested object renders in the `Template`, as of Meteor 0.5.3 you can update sub arrays simply:

```
Sprints.update(Sprints.findOne()._id, { $set: { "WorkStories.0.name": "updated_name1" } });
```

**BACKGROUND INFO**

This does load the initial object, but updating seems problematic. I was able to get the Template to rerender by calling the below in the console:

```
Sprints.update(Sprints.findOne()._id, { name: 'sprint777', WorkStories: [{ name: 'workStory1232', Tasks: [{ name: 'task221' }, { name: 'task2' }, { name: 'task3' }] }, { name: 'workStory2', Tasks: [{ name: 'task1' }, { name: 'task2' }, { name: 'task3' }] }] })
```

Which follows these rules, per the [Meteor Docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#modifiers):

> But if a modifier doesn't contain any $-operators, then it is instead interpreted as a literal document, and completely replaces whatever was previously in the database. (Literal document modifiers are not currently supported by validated updates.

Of course, what you want is to use the `$set` style operators on nested documents and get the templates to re-render when their nested properties change **without** having to replace the entire document in the table. [The 0.5.3 version of Meteor](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/v0.5.3/History.md) included the ability to search for sub-arrays:

`Allow querying specific array elements (foo.1.bar).`

I've tried to do the `.` sub array search and haven't been able to update the `WorkStories` subdocument of the original entity yet, so I [posted a question](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/meteor-talk/bRIQCOHc99c) in the google talk.

Hope this helps

Comment: This does not work. It will load the initial object, but if I make changes to the `workStories` collection, it is not reflected in the template.

Comment: You're right, I've made an update to my question and posted in the meteor google group.

Comment: I've just tried your example and this appears to work:

`Sprints.update(Sprints.findOne()._id, { $set: { "WorkStories.0.name": "updated_name1" } })` note the placement of quotes